# How can I update this compensation data between arrays?

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook, with two sheets (sheet 1 & sheet 2).  Sheet 1 has columns A:E (TSR = Target Salary Range)

`Job Code` `job title` `TSR min` `TSR mid` `TSR max`

`10001` `job 1` `55k` `60k` `65K`

`10003` `job 3` `65k` `70k` `75K`

`10005` `job 3` `75k` `80k` `85K`

on my Sheet 2, I have updated figures for only two of the jobs:

`Job Code` `job title` `TSR min` `TSR mid` `TSR max`

`10001` `job 1` `65k` `70k` `75K`

`10005` `job 3` `85k` `90k` `95K`

based on Sheet2, I want to only update the numbers in columns C:E of jobs 1 and 3, and do not change job 2's salary bands.

Here is code I've tried but I'm not getting a subscript error on this line: `Set varSheetB = wbkA.Sheets(2)`, and I in general don't think I'm quite there (why Im reaching out here).

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wbkA As Workbook
Dim varSheetA As Variant, varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long 'I'll want to check for differing values between columns C:E

Set wbkA = ThisWorkbook

Set varSheetA = wbkA.Sheets(1)
Set varSheetB = wbkA.Sheets(2)

strRangeToCheck = "A2:E3000"

varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck)

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)

    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)

        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then '
           varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol)
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If

    Next iCol

Next iRow

End Sub
```

I'll link screenshots if necessary, but just imagine both takes starting in A1 (with the headers)

[image: worksheet]

The sheet shows the OG stuff your code updates, but then it has iterations of slightly higher salaries that’ll need to also be updated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code to clean it up and make it more efficient. First, since Sheet2 contains all of the changes, we will be looping over that sheet and searching for the values in sheet 1. This is more efficient because it doesn't waste operations looping through the cells in sheet1 that don't have any changes.

Additionally, I've made the Ranges dynamic so you're not constrained to range "A2:E3000" in all cases. If I understand correctly, sheet2 will be a subset of sheet1, so there are cases where it will have less rows. No reason to loop over blank rows.

Finally, I use the `Match` function to search for matches. Keep in mind that the function returns the position relative to the range. So, if you are searching for a match in Range("A5:A10"), and the match is found in cell `A5`, the function will return 1 (not 5). That's why I offset the `fndRow` variable.

Let me know if this works for you or if you have additional questions.

```
 Sub Test()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wsB As Worksheet
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim rIterator As Range
    Dim fndRow As Long

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsA = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsB = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'CurrentRegion should work to bring in the entire
    'necessary range so long as it is contiguous data
    Set rngA = wsA.Range(wsA.Range("A2"), wsA.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set rngB = wsB.Range(wsB.Range("A2"), wsB.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    For Each rIterator In rngB
        On Error Resume Next
        fndRow = Application.Match(rIterator.Value, rngA, 0) + _
            rngA.Range("A1").Row - 1
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'What happens if it isn't found?
        Else
            wsA.Cells(fndRow, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value
            wsA.Cells(fndRow, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value
            wsA.Cells(fndRow, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value

            wsA.Cells(fndRow + 1, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * 1.1
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + 1, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value * 1.1
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + 1, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value * 1.1

            wsA.Cells(fndRow + 2, 3).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 2).Value * 1.2
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + 2, 4).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 3).Value * 1.2
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + 2, 5).Value = rIterator.Offset(, 4).Value * 1.2

            '.... Repeat for all rows
        End If

        Err.Clear

    Next rIterator

 End Sub
```

Comment: ok this is AMAZING, I do have one more question. 

So lets say Each job code has the TSR, but that's for a zone 1 (small city), while a zone 5 would be for like NYC pay-grade. 

would it be a lot harder to make sure that each row of changed salary data would be multiplied for the next 4 rows(zone 2,3,4,5) reflecting the zone 1 salary data? `zone 2 would be 1.1*zone 1`,  `zone 3 would be 1.15*zone1`,`zone 4 would be 1.2*zone 1`, `zone5 would be 1.3*zone 1`. 

Attaching my post with a screenshot of what I am referencing.

Comment: Ok, edited my post to show the worksheet and what Im talking about and to see if it's even possible. Is this doable with a simple `Case` statement with the 1.1,1.15,1.2,1.3 multipliers from the rows we're initially updating with whats in sheet 2?

Comment: @nicklanta I made an edit to my post to hopefully address this. So long as you always have the same layout (where the 4 following rows follow the pattern), it's a relatively simple, although slightly tedious fix. Let me know if that works out.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Is there a way to maybe implement a `Do until A2<>A3` kind of thing? I think it should stay consistent at one OG row and then the following 4, just curious.

Comment: do you know how I'd apply something like `activecell.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)` so I can highlight the cells that have been adjusted?

Comment: @nicklanta You can create a loop to check. Are the cells below actually blank? Or is there a not visible value?

Comment: I can figure it out later, no worries, but how would I incorporate the cell highlighting once the value has been adjusted? I figure I'm close with that snipped I provided, just don't know where to place it in code

Comment: @nicklanta You're actually pretty close. Since you have row that you're working with, and since you will always be updating 5 rows, you can do something like: `wsA.Range(wsA.cells(fndRow, 1), wsA.cells(fndRow,5)).resize(5).interior.color = RGB(181, 244, 0)`.

Comment: can't thank you enough, I may make another post tomorrow/Monday to add on a few things, but you seriously helped a lot, and I can learn a lot from this. Thanks and have a great night!!!